# Is there a performance improvement when considering partition size during HDD partition?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, performance

I am having a 320GB (298GB usable) HDD. I want to partition it.

Generally, Is there a recommended fixed size for partitioning so as to get more performance?
Like in what case will the performance will be the best?

> a) Creating equally sized partitions will give best performance/access
>   times.
>
> b) It doesn't really matter, but partitions in  initial sectors will
>   have faster access times.

Consider if I choose b); Can I create a 60GB partition as C: and rest as 80GB partitions?, will it affect the performance in any way compared to a)?

Comment: a search like http://superuser.com/search?q=partitioning+performance will get you enough information to decide for your uses. I could not find a perfect single Q&A that covers it all, but it has all been covered before.

Comment: Well I agree, but my question is not Will partitioning will affect performance?, but like does partition size affects performance. That's why I've decided to ask a new question.

Comment: B) it just walls off sections of a disk, might help with organisation, partition to partition copying will be no faster than before, (only seperate hard disks solution the from/to data copy thing). There might be some reduced fragmenting, easier to defrag smaller sections. could be easier to manage or way worse to manage . moves within partitions dont actually move data but just re-point to it , wheras moves from partition to partition require total re-write. It is way more Users Choice of how you can organise the data, waste the space, or keep it in the faster sections. All covered before.